# Как можно сравнить элементы массива?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Здраствуйте. Мне нужно добавить в программу сравнение: верно ли , что название пунктов назначения совпадают у двух поездов. Я не знаю как это сделать. Можете подсказать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;

struct Train {
    char name[40];
    int number;
    double times;

} train[SIZE];

void enter(),init_list(),display(),input(int i);
int menu();

int main()
{
    char choice;
    init_list();
    while (1) {
        choice = menu();
        switch(choice) {
            case 'e' : enter();
            break;
            case 'd' : display();
            break;
            //case 'u': update();
            break;
            case 'q': return 0;

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
void init_list()
{
    int t;

    for(t=0; t<SIZE; t++ ) *train[t].name = '\0';
}
int menu()
{
        char ch;
        cout << '\n';
        do {
            cout << "(E)nter\n"; // Ввести новый элемент.
            cout << "(D)isplay\n"; // Отобразить всю ведомость.
            cout << "(Q)uit\n\n"; // Выйти из программы.
            cout << "Выберите команду: ";
            cin >> ch;
        }while(!strchr("eduq", tolower(ch)));
    return tolower(ch);
}
void enter()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        if(!*train[i].name) break;

    if(i==SIZE) {
        cout << "Список полон.\n";
    return;
    }
    input(i);
}
void input(int i) {
    cout <<"Пункт назначения: ";
     cin >>train[i].name;
     cout <<endl;
    cout <<"Номер поезда: ";
     cin >>train[i].number;
    cout <<"Время отправления: ";
     cin >>train[i].times;
}

void display()
{
    int t;
    for(t=0; t<SIZE; t++) {
        if(*train[t].name) {
            cout << "Пункт назначения: " << train[t].name <<endl;
            cout << "Номер поезда: " << train[t].number <<endl;
            cout << "Время отправления: " << train[t].times<<endl;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если описать как string

```
string name;
```

Тогда сравнение корректно с использованием == 
Также cstring надежнее и получится с++, а не смесь с С.
Вы задали длину 40. А если будет введено больше? С string об этом не надо беспокоиться.

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения С-строк есть функция strcmp.